# React. Компоненты

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Изучая react наткнулся на интересную с моей точки зрения конструкцию в react-bootstrap:

```js
<Nav
  activeKey="/home"
  onSelect={selectedKey => alert(`selected ${selectedKey}`)}>
  <Nav.Item>
    <Nav.Link href="/home">Active</Nav.Link>
  </Nav.Item>
  <Nav.Item>
    <Nav.Link eventKey="link-1">Link</Nav.Link>
  </Nav.Item>
  <Nav.Item>
    <Nav.Link eventKey="link-2">Link</Nav.Link>
  </Nav.Item>
  <Nav.Item>
    <Nav.Link eventKey="disabled" disabled>
      Disabled
    </Nav.Link>
  </Nav.Item>
</Nav>
```

Что такое Nav.Item, где можно про это почитать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это просто способ структурирования кода.

`Nav.Item` это такой же компонент, как и любой другой обычный компонент `React`. Но, в данном случае, мы используем `namespace` для того, что бы точно знать, какой именно компонент используем. Посмотрите сами, `Item` очень обобщенное имя, поэтому другие библиотеки могут тоже его использовать

```
import {Item} from 'one-lib';
import {Item} from 'two-lib'; // Oooops. Duplicate name!
```

Да, можно выкрутиться используя конструкцию `as`, но это не так красиво)

```
import {Item} from 'one-lib';
import {Item as ItemTwo} from 'two-lib'; // Ok
```

Поэтому, разработчик может не волноваться за проблему дубликата имен, а создать свой `namespace`, где будет уже иметь свои стандартные и уникальные, в рамках своей либы, названия

```
import {Nav} from 'lib';

Nav.Component1; // Ok!
Nav.Component2; // Ok too!

// В коде либы

export Nav = {
   Component1: ...,
   Component2: ...,
}
```

При этом `Nav` сам может являться компонентом, тогда остальные будут статическими св-свами

```
class Nav extends React.Component {}; // Тут уже используются эта техника - React.Component

Nav.Component1 = class Component1 extends React.Component {}
Nav.Component2 = class Component1 extends React.Component {}

export Nav
```

**Почитать**
[`namespace`](https://habr.com/ru/post/31596/)